# Transaction DELETE. Missing row in SELECT query. Is opened transaction still locking "deleted" rows for only one connection? [MariaDb 10.3.11]

Tags: mariadb

Below code:

```
START TRANSACTION;
    DELETE FROM invoice_mails WHERE consignment_id=1 AND status='READY';
    DELETE FROM consignment_invoices WHERE consignment_id=1;
    DELETE FROM consignments WHERE consignment_id=1;
COMMIT;
```

produces foreign key constraint error. This error is expected.

Deletions are rollbacked on error.

```
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`consignment_integrator`.`invoice_mails`, CONSTRAINT `consignments_consignment_id` FOREIGN KEY (`consignment_id`) REFERENCES `consignments` (`consignment_id`))'"
```

The problem is with query executed in the same db connection:

```
Select * from consignment_invoices WHERE consignment_id=1;
```

it does not return row.

Same selection executed in an other in connection returns expected row.

I can't find solution. Is opened transaction still locking "deleted" rows for only one connection?

Comment: `mariaDB` OR `MySQL`?

Comment: MariaDB 10.3.11

Comment: Is that `SELECT` inside the transaction?  How do you catch the error and do the ROLLBACK?  What are the indexes on the tables?